# Como saber que o atributo é not null no banco PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Java com Spring Boot e criei a tabela como `not null` como podem ver:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    codigo BIGSERIAL,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
);
```

O problem foi que conseguir cadastra no banco como `null` não era pra ter acontecido isso, eu fiz uma breve pesquisa na internet e encontre esse comando para saber a descrição da minha tabela;

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='categoria';
```

Mas ele somente me trás essa informação, ele não me diz se de fato foi criado a tabela como `not null`.

[image: Verificação que está certo]

Como faço para saber se a tabela está como `not null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou responder o que perguntou embora a pergunta deveria ser sobre o que está fazendo errado para ter aceito `NULL`.

Está procurando pela coluna `is_nullable`, da tabela `information_schema.columns` é ela que indica se uma coluna de uma tabela é anulável ou não. Obviamente que se você pega só o nome não vem esta informação.

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'categoria';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/IsNullable.sql).

[Documentação da tabela de colunas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html).

Comment: por favor, como irei executar esse comando na minha tabela?

Comment: Você não sabe sabe usar um simples `SELECT`? Então Tenho a impressão que está fazendo algo que está acima do que conhece, eu iria para coisas mais simples antes de tentar fazer algo complexo, porque isto é o básico do básico do SQL. Mas eu coloquei para você.

Comment: muito obrigado :)